# Copying multiple resource directories to independent target directories with maven

Tags: java, maven

The [Maven resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/):

> This goal requires that you configure the resources to be copied, and specify the outputDirectory.

Copy two (or more) external resource directories within the `basedir` to the build output directory using maven (see `blah` and `uggh`).

```
${basedir}/ 
  - pom.xml
  - blah/
  - uggh/
  - src/
    - main/..
    - test/..
  - target/
    - classes/..
    - blah/
    - uggh/
```

For example, given the directory structure above copy `blah` and `uggh` to the target directory using maven. It is easy to copy one or the other, however, the plugin only accepts a single outputDirectory. If you specify the `target` directory and both directories as resources, then the contents of each directory gets copied to `target` but not the directories themselves.

Additional use of the plugin overwrites the initial. Also, I've tried specifying the entire `basedir` and only including the desired directories. This does not copy anything.

Here is an example of copying a single directory:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/blah</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>blah</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

This is where the file ends up:

```
<outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/blah</outputDirectory>
```

This is where it is copied from:

```
<directory>src/main/otherresources</directory>
```

There would be an `<include>` or `<includes>` tag to tell the file name(s)

**Multiples**

You need multiple `<execution>`s with different `<id>`s for multiple folders:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources-1</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/blah</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>blah</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources-2</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/ughh</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>ughh</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: where are the folders on file systen? src/main/resources/ughh ?

Comment: i am using maven 3.3.3 is this still possible?

Comment: ${basedir} is the root folder of your workspace. It is the folder with the pom.xml in it.

Answer (score 23):

For me this one works well in Maven 3:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>custom-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>                                        
                            <resource>
                                <targetPath>${basedir}/target/blah</targetPath>
                                <directory>blah</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>             
                            <resource>
                                <targetPath>${basedir}/target/uggh</targetPath>
                                <directory>uggh</directory>
                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                            </resource>              
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>            
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: This would dump all the contents of `blah` and `uggh` to `target` but not the directories themselves in my case. Not exactly  what I'm looking for but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: It's not clear to me from the config alone, how I would expect this to behave. From the Maven docs, `<targetPath>` " is relative to the target/classes directory". http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Resource.html#setTargetPath(java.lang.String)

Comment: I just tried this out and it also works for the "maven-war-plugin" as well

Comment: As I noticed u ever don't need to set `<outputDirectory>` if u specify the `<targetPath>` for both different directories is different

Answer (score 14):

This is the simpler solution I've found and it's working...

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>   
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins> 
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/org/mc2/mymusic/gui/main/Menu/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${basedir}/target/classes/org/mc2/mymusic/gui/main/Menu/resources</targetPath>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>  
</build>
```

Comment: works for me even without filtering section (as I use it for plain files), nice and neat syntax

Comment: This works for me without the plugin element. I just used the resources element.

Answer (score 11):

You can use ant-style patterns

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>blah/**</include>
                            <include>uggh/**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
              <directory>${basedir}/src/scripts</directory>
              <includes>
                  <include>data-octopus.ps1</include>
              </includes>
              <targetPath>${basedir}/target/data</targetPath>
        </resource>
        <resource>
              <directory>${basedir}/src/scripts</directory>
              <includes>
                  <include>service-octopus.ps1</include>
              </includes>
              <targetPath>${basedir}/target/service</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    </plugins>
        ...
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 3):

Reading your example I don't think you have to include&configure the maven-resource-plugin.
Just add those resource-elements to the `<build><resources/>`-tag. See http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-model/maven.html#class_resource which other tags you can use.

Comment: You are right. It was just to show a slightly less verbose way to use maven-resource-plugin. And for this case, to preserve the source folder names on output directory.

Answer (score 0):

Maven hides everything to make it easier to code.
There are several ways you can achieve this.

1. Edit the default execution in Resources plugin. (Easiest)
   This also can be written using include tag or different resources
2. Write different executions in Resources plugin.
3. Use Antrun plugin. (You might as well write the whole build in ant)
4. Maven Copy-rename plugin.
5. And many other ways that I am not mentioning here....

Edit the default plugin--

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}<directory>
        <includes>
            <include>blah</include>
            <include>ughh</include>
        </includes>
    <resource>
<resources>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy more directories or files - a better option:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <copy todir="${basedir}/target/blah" overwrite="true">
                 <fileset dir="blah"/>
            </copy>
            <copy file="${basedir}/target/blah/somefile"
                  todir="../target_webapp_eclaims/WEB-INF" overwrite="true"/>
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <targetPath>${basedir}/target</targetPath>
          </resource>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <targetPath>${basedir}/target/classes</targetPath>
          </resource>
       </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>jks</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources-1</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
   </plugins>
```

[image: Maven - Copying resources into multiple targets]