# How do I specify a directory prefix on a set of resources in maven's pom.xml

Tags: maven

I have a set of files I'd like to include in the .jar generated by `mvn compile`.  Unfortunately, I would like them to be placed in a specific path inside the .jar.  For example, I want shaders/main.glsl to be in the .jar file as com/purplefrog/expglsl/castle/main.glsl

How do I specify this mapping in the pom.xml ?  I can not mess with the directory heirarchy of the source project without throwing a wrench into other coders' workflows.

Comment: Put the class in `src/main/resources/com/purplefrog/expglsl/castle/main.glsl` and it will be automatically there. If this will mess others sounds like you violate SRP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the `process-resources` phase non-compilable files can be moved (by the [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/)). What you should do is add a [resource-block](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) to your pom. Here you need to specify the `directory`. You can also add a [targetPath](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-model/maven.html#class_resource). All together it would look like

```
<resource>
  <directory>shaders</directory>
  <!-- include all ore just a couple of files? -- >
  <includes>
    <include>main.glsl</include>
  </includes>
  <targetPath>com/purplefrog/expglsl/castle</targetPath>
</resource>
```

Now these files are copied to the `target/classes` and during the `package` phase they'll become part of the jar.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409220/copying-multiple-resource-directories-to-independent-target-directories-with-mav).

Sounds like that should handle what you're looking to do if modifying the project structure up front isn't an option.