# refreshing the page results in 401 error- Angular 8

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-ui-router

when I hit**http://localhost:4200** or **http://localhost:4200/forgotPasswordEmail** on my local environment, it works correctly.

Opening the index-page on my production environment and clicking a link to go to another page, also works. However, when I refresh the page or go directly to `http://<prod url>/forgotPasswordEmail`, it doesn't work and then I get the following error:

[image: error page]

I guess that when I hit the URL, it's trying to search the rest API code for `forgotPasswordEmail` and it's not able to find the
value so it's returning 401 but locally it's working fine.

Comment: What kind of server is serving the angular app?

Comment: This happens because Angular doesn't really serve anything at `/forgotPasswordEmail`. Frameworks like Angular use a JavaScript API to do that. To make this work, you need to configure the web server to redirect all calls back to `index.html` so that your Angular app can handle it. For Spring boot, this is covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43913753/1915448).

Comment: Thanks for the post and I am trying this solution

Comment: no luck from this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will achieve this through

```
security.basic.enable: false
security.ignored=/**
```

Answer (score 1):

In your server config, you need to render index.html every route that is not a static file or folder. Routing should be handled by the angular application, not the server.

Comment: can you please elaborate Thanks!