# How to add resource folder to the my EJB jar by maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, ejb, ear, java-ee-7

We have a **resources** folder in our EAR, this folder contains some image,xml and text files. 
I need to add this folder to our EJBs manifest classpath.

```
myEAR
|-> resources 
|     |-> myXml.xml
|     |-> mytext.txt
|->lib
|   |-> pojo1.jar
|   |-> pojo2.jar 
|->ejb.jar
```

currently, my maven ear plugin adds our *.jar to my EJB jar classpath, for example, our ejb.jar manifest look like blowing:

```
Class-Path: lib/pojo1.jar lib/pojo2.jar
```

but I need to add our "**resources**" folder to this classpath too:

```
Class-Path: resources lib/pojo1.jar lib/pojo2.jar
```

Comment: In EAR file? Simply no. An EAR file is an container and does not contain resources etc. only the containing jar's/war's could contain resources...

Comment: I agree, But this is an old project and its EAR contain a resources folder!

Comment: The resources will be packaged into the ear file (If i correctly remember) and that means the files are on the classpath of the EAR...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find a solution for that. we are adding the resources folder to the classpath by using  tag in EJB module POM file:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.ejb.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>${version.ejbImpl}</ejbVersion>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                         <Class-Path>resources</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should work if resources folder is a top level folder in your maven project.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
        <directory>resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources> 
</build>
```

If it is not a top level folder, try to leverage src/main/resources folder which by default puts everything under it into the target artifact.

Comment: I hope you have added above in ejb's pom and not in ear pom. If yes, use maven-jar-plugin to control entries in manifest.mf.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your comment. but it doesn't what is I am looking for!
First: my " resources" folder is in my maven ear module and if I add this folder as a <resources> in my EJB module or as a <earSourceDirectory> then maven add content of the resources to root of JAR or EAR but I need to package my EAR in a way that my resources folder placed in the root of EAR and when I want to load the content of my resource folder I just mention the resource name.

Comment: I mean i like to use 
tread.getContextClassLoader()
    .getResource("myXml.xml")
and not using the  falowwing :
tread.getContextClassLoader()
    .getResource("resources\myXml.xml")

thanks again

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/19409280/1352127. You can specify the output directory as per your need.