# Zip multiple files/folders from the workspace directory using zip utility

Tags: jenkins

We have a Jenkins pipeline and I want to zip multiple files(.py and .cfg) located in multiple directories within my workspace. Is there a way we can pass multiple values to **dir** option of the zip method?

```
zip (zipFile: "package.zip", dir: "${WORKSPACE}/infra/folder1/")
```

P.S: I can add an additional stage before zip process and move all the required files to a folder and archive that folder using above zip method, but I would like to avoid an additional step/stage

Comment: just an idea here... you could pass the workspace as your `dir` and play with`glob` parameter to specify the file names that start with the folders that you want

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at the sources for that [JENKINS Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Utility+Steps+Plugin) in [`jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin):

- [`zip/ZipStep.java`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/0b912dac3870b880d354dcbe0d21cfff4b08ff93/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/zip/ZipStep.java)
- [`zip/ZipStepExecution.java`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/0b912dac3870b880d354dcbe0d21cfff4b08ff93/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/zip/ZipStepExecution.java)

Nothing suggests you could:

- pass multiple directories
- execute the zip step multiple times for one archive, *appending* folders to an existing archive

So you have to:

- either, as suggested, use the [right shell glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))
- make a pre-step in which you [copy multiple folder top one common folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19409220/6309), where you can then apply the `zip` step.